# redhawk fastfilter Designer

Tags: redhawksdr

How do I access the fastfilter block filter designer? When I instantiate the fastfilter block in the chalkboard and change filter parameters nothing happens. Shouldn't it calculate the taps and update them in the "realFilterCoefficients" property?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the taps make their way out and into the properties. One reason why it may not be an easy feature to add is because the component can handle multiple streams and each stream could have a different sample rate. The sample rate is used when calculating the taps so each stream could have different taps.

Answer (score 0):

The technical reason it wasn't done is because the taps change with different sample rates. As such, you would have to update the taps property whenever the sample rate changes and this becomes problematic with different streams with different sample rates.

We chose not to implment this due to the cost of the memory copies for updating the taps to display the most recent set based upon the most recent sample rates. This cost is non-trivial as the number of taps goes up and sample rates change periodically.

An alternative approach would be to build a command line utility that links against the dsp library and spits out taps to the screen for a given set of command line parameters.